# TRON blockchain: create, sign and broadcast transaction via API of public node

Tags: broadcast, tron

Im php developer and trying to broadcast tron transaction. pls do not advice to me java libs. i think this operation can be made by API calls.

im understand 3 steps: create, sign and broadcast

**step 1**: use https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/createtransaction
and get raw_data_hex
result: `0a02df8d22080ffa79d7279ecb2a40a88bc8d9ba2e5a65080112610a2d747970652e676f6f676c65617069732e636f6d2f70726f746f636f6c2e5472616e73666572436f6e747261637412300a1541e3b634e89a3edd652651b5c775870fc364cf2a061215413131e7dd9fe0ce528f9d86036fcfef56967d8807180170ecc8c4d9ba2e`

**step 2**: create sign by steps from https://developers.tron.network/docs/account#signature
result: `6bca53954ac706ddf59745e0e9d09e7c3709e58d1bdf35a06d0b974c1eaa0eca695d7b2aecd7200988f415a447e70064939ba56a6dd3c71725c547f3452ffaef00`

and "Add this signature back into the transaction":
`0a02df8d22080ffa79d7279ecb2a40a88bc8d9ba2e5a65080112610a2d747970652e676f6f676c65617069732e636f6d2f70726f746f636f6c2e5472616e73666572436f6e747261637412300a1541e3b634e89a3edd652651b5c775870fc364cf2a061215413131e7dd9fe0ce528f9d86036fcfef56967d8807180170ecc8c4d9ba2e6bca53954ac706ddf59745e0e9d09e7c3709e58d1bdf35a06d0b974c1eaa0eca695d7b2aecd7200988f415a447e70064939ba56a6dd3c71725c547f3452ffaef00`

**step 3**: broadcast this by https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/broadcasthex
result:
`{"Error":"class com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException : While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length."}`

that i did wrong?

also i tryed to use https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/gettransactionsign with only two parameters raw_data_hex and privateKey (i think this enought to sign)
but got error:
`{"Error":"class java.lang.NullPointerException : null"}`

im confused...

P.S. MAIN question is:
how to prepare/build data to pass to API [/wallet/broadcasthex](https://developers.tron.network/reference#broadcasthex) ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf must be handled by protobuf libs. Use field getting/setting method.
Not Binary Concat.

Comment: Why not? This working good in other cryptocurrencies. Can you show example of proper data for this API (broadcasthex)?